# How to find the target PowerShell version of a module not yet installed?

Tags: powershell

I can query a module I want to install using

```
Find-Module -Name AzureAD
```

However, I must know beforehand that this module can only be installed in PowerShell v5/Desktop and not PowerShell v7/Core, otherwise I might install it or try to run it in the wrong version and get all sorts of issues.

Apparently it should be possible to find this information using the 'Tag' property:

```
Find-Module -Tag PSEdition_Desktop
Find-Module -Tag PSEdition_Core
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/gallery/concepts/module-psedition-support?view=powershellget-3.x

However, it doesn't seem to work (perhaps the module authors do not bother filling in this value).

Is there any way to find the target PowerShell version of a module before installing it?

Comment: Why is it important that it's not compatible with PowerShell 7? Lots of 5.1 code is still valid in 7

Comment: it matters because someone can attemp to install a module only to realize later on that it doesn't work and then has to proceed to uninstall and reinstall it in the right version. a simple validation could help mitigate the issue at an early stage and save valuable time. the problem is that we can *install* any module even if it's not compatible

Comment: So if a module works in 5.1, but also works in 7, then you don't want to install it?

Comment: Can you provide the names of one or more module with which this is the situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the `Find-Module` command and use the `AdditionalMetadata` property.

[image: AdditionalMetadata]

But I think this could be the same result as your `-Tag` thing.

Comment: this is actually the very same property I'm looking at :) in the absense of anything else, I think this will do

Comment: Nice. Sadly, this information seems to be no longer part of the output objects of `Find-Module`'s successor command, [`Find-PSResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.psresourceget/find-psresource), as of v1.0.1 of the `Microsoft.PowerShell.PSResourceGet` module - though that could be a bug. See [GitHub issue #1496](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSResourceGet/issues/1496).

Comment: I was running the `Find-Module` command at this moment on a newly installed pc. ‍♂️ There may be a bug in the system. Idk.